# Using Java's Fork/Join library from Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am a newbie trying to learn some Java and I am reading [prof. Dan Grossman](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/)'s introductory lecture notes [on parallel and concurrent algorithms](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/teachingMaterials/spac/).

I wrote a version of a divide-and-conquer algorithm for summing an array of integers using both bare-bones Java `Thread`s and one that uses the new (in Java 7) [Fork/Join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Since I am learning things, just for fun I tried the same summing array in Scala, but I feel that my implementation could use a lot of improvements (I am even more of a newbie in Scala than I am in Java, which says a lot).

```
package cc.cynic.jvmtests.threading

import java.util.concurrent.{ ForkJoinPool, RecursiveTask }

class ScalaSumArray(val lo: Int, val hi: Int, val arr: Array[Int]) extends RecursiveTask[Int] {
  val SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD = 1

  def mysum(lo: Int, hi: Int) = {
    val r = lo until hi
    (for (i <- r) yield arr(i)).sum
  }

  def compute: Int = {
      if (hi - lo <= SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD)
        mysum(lo, hi)
      else {
        val left = new ScalaSumArray(lo, (lo + hi) / 2, arr)
        val right = new ScalaSumArray((lo + hi) / 2, hi, arr)

        left.fork()
        val rightans = right.compute()
        val leftans = left.join()
        leftans + rightans
      }
  }
}

object ScalaSumArray {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fjpool: ForkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool
    val lo = 0
    val hi = 10001
    val r = lo until hi
    val arr: Array[Int] = r.toArray

    // Without parallelism
    val foo = new ScalaSumArray(lo, hi, arr)
    println(foo.mysum(lo, hi))

    // With parallelism
    val s = new ScalaSumArray(lo, hi, arr)
    println(fjpool.invoke(s))
  }
}
```

The source code for this is available on [my Github account](https://github.com/rbrito/java-tests/blob/70eed471ceb17ec9fe89949bc69b0510d7e4279c/src/main/scala/cc/cynic/jvmtests/threading/ScalaSumArray.scala), if you wish to see it there. The corresponding Java version [is here](https://github.com/rbrito/java-tests/blob/314566ab04d413399a6b01f150dacebc8687b74f/src/cc/cynic/jvmtests/threading/ThreadingTest007.java).

Again, since I am a novice with Scala, Java and parallel programming, I would appreciate any kind of feedback to improve/simplify the code.

Comment: I don't want to hold you back from learning this stuff. Please go on and work on it like you are doing. It will improve your knowledge and skills. On the other side: If you want to process something in parallel in Scala for practical use you will probably use `Future`s, `Actor`s and reactive streams. Probably you use the Akka Framework (http://akka.io). I think under the hood of those APIs the Java ThreadPool / Executor stuff is still in use (I think even with the Fork/Join-Algorithm), but you can work with the mentioned top-level APIs which make parallelism much easier.

Comment: Not a full review: `mysum()` is a silly name. Is it pertinent which code is yours and which code isn't? The argument names, `lo` and `hi`, are mildly confusing because they shadow (same name) outside variables. The code can be simplified to `Range(lo,hi).map(arr).sum`.